# Prohibit installers from modifying Windows Firewall rules

Tags: windows-7, windows, firewall, installer, windows-firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent applications from modifying Windows 7 firewall policy](https://superuser.com/questions/467455/how-to-prevent-applications-from-modifying-windows-7-firewall-policy)

Comment: You can click the Edit link on that question, and try to reword it. It will be placed in the Edit queue, and users with more reputation can vote to accept your edit as useful

Comment: I added a answer to the other question that I think covers what you are wanting.